# SharePoint 2013 Search navigation links are not clickable

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I have added custom search verticals and the first two links are working fine. Once I click on the third link i cannot click on any other link. Can somebody help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This post has been here for a while and probably you already solved the issue. However, just in case someone else is having the same behavior I run into the same issue today. In my case, the problem was related to the fact that the result source used in the additional vertical was the same as the result source used on a different vertical, but using a different query. I just changed the settings of the results webpart on the additional vertical and the issue disapeared.

Hope it helps.